# Twilio Message Params Empty

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am testing out Twilio and am attempting to receive an SMS message. When I send a text, my app route is getting triggered as expected, however the "params" are empty. I've tried both `post` and `get`. Using Express (and Coffeescript), here is what I've got (not much to it):

```
app.post '/receive', (req, res) ->
  console.log req.params
```

In this case, it logs out an empty object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.params` [refers to URL parameters in Express 4](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#request).  Twilio sends HTTP POST parameters (by default) with a webhook request.  Are you using a body parser middleware?

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

With this module, if you use the form-encoded middleware, the parameters sent from a Twilio POST request will be in `req.body`.  If Twilio sends you a GET, the parameters should be in `req.query` without using any additional middleware.

Thanks,
-Kevin

Comment: Yup, that was it! Duh :)

Comment: Want to mark it as correct so folks find it as such in search?  Thanks :)